# Memory issues calling setTimeout() to the function I am calling it from?

Tags: javascript

I have the following function:

```
var counter = 0;

test();

function test() {
    counter++;
    alert(counter);
    setTimeout(function() { test() }, 100);
}
```

Will this create any issues with memory? ie: will the test() function exit normally before it is called again by setTimeout()?

My tests show that it does exit before calling the function again, but a co-worker is certain it will cause memory issues.

Update:
I ran a test with Chrome and watched its Task Manager, and the memory usage didn't change.

```
testSetTimeout(0);

function testSetTimeout(a) {
    $("body").html(a);
    var v = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < 20000; i++)
        v.push("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    setTimeout(function () { testSetTimeout(a + 1); }, 0);
}
```

However, when changing this code to call testSetTimeout() directly, it executed about 8000 times and then crapped out, in Chrome.

Comment: I don't see how this can possibly cause memory issues.  `setTimeout` doesn't run its argument immediately or on the same function call stack as its caller.  If your coworker feels there's potential for a problem, they should demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine, since the call to test() will be put on the call stack of setTimeout's function, not test(), so you won't blow up the stack

Comment: That was what I thought, and it makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `test()` is called, a new instance of it is created. That instance has to maintain a relationship with where it was called from, otherwise it becomes a 'zombie'.  Any time you have a self-replicating zombie in the code it is not a good code.  On the other hand, if it does not become a zombie and maintains that reference to where it was called from, you have an unintended recursion which is basically a memory leak.  The proper way to do this and not have memory wasted would be:

```
setInterval(test, 100};
function test(){
    doWHATEVER…
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes , As you said it will cause the memory issue . When `test()` called for the first time `setTimeout()` would maintain the scope of initial trigger. Every functional call will keep `setTimeout()` in stack and will cause memory leak because of stack full.

```
var counter = 0;

test();

function test() {
  counter++;
  if(counter >20) return; // This will make the function to exit.
  setTimeout(function() { test() }, 100);
}
```

Comment: This is wrong.  `setTimeout` does not invoke its argument on the calling functions stack.  "Code executed by `setTimeout()` is called from an execution context separate from the function from which setTimeout was called."  It runs on a *new* call stack.  If `test()` called itself directly, by invoking itself, then yes, your answer would be correct.

Comment: My test code confirms that there's no memory leak, at least in Chrome